# my memcached server have to be "flush_all" per about 12 hours ,unless the app would down soon

Tags: memcached, installation, configure

my memcached server have to be "flush_all" per about 12 hours ,unless the app would down soon.

if i ignore some memcached settings?  my app based on java/tomcat

i startup memcached by typed "nohup ./memcached -p [port] -m 8192"  that all,

i' can't found the configure file of my memcached server.

i installing memcached  by typed tar zxf memcached-version.tar.gz

cd memcached-version/

./configure -prefix /usr

make && make install

Answer (score 0):

How much memory do you have on that machine?  if you have 8G, what might be happening is that memcached is taking up all the memory available on the machine.

if so, just change the memcached startupline to -m 5000 or so.